# Whats the point of methods and functions in C#?

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I don't really grasp the point of methods/functions in C#. I need some clarification/reasoning. Look at the code for reference

---

### why do i have to make a method:

```
string color;

if (color == "red")
{
    Text();
}

void Text();
{
    Console.WriteLine("you chose " + color)
}
```

---

### when you can make it without using a method:

```
if (color == "red")
{
    Console.WriteLine("you chose red")
}
```

Comment: Because in production code things are a lot more complex than this. It is not good practice to lump all logic in one place. It is so hard to write automated tests if you don’t split things up into small readable chunks. Small, well defined methods that do one thing and one thing well are best for readability.

Comment: Makes no sense for a single line, single use piece of code. The real world is just a little more complex.

Comment: What if the colour becomes blue or green? This way you have one object. Please read up on functions etc in a tutorial. Best way.

Comment: I think doing some actual real-world programming will rapidly make it clear why you want methods and semblance of order in your code. I have some code that updates data in an ElasticSearch database from a Mongo database. I call to that in maybe 25 different places. The code is about 50 lines long (between retrieving data and writing data). Can you imagine writing 50 lines of code in 25 different places? Can you imagine having to make a change to that piece of code in 25 different places?

Comment: In short it helps you reuse code (instead of writing the exact same code twice) and they help you to structure your program for better readability and maintainability (instead of having 1000s or 1,000,000s lines of code without any structure).

Answer (score 2):

Main reason I have is reusability and separation of responsibility

In your example, what if the `string color;` is user input

then you will have multiple if for types of `color`

lets expand your example and your answer

```
string color = //userinput;

if (color == "red")... if (color == "blue")... if (color == "yellow")
```

so on and so forth but if you want to use the two methods it will only boil down to one

```
string color = //userinput

void Text();
{
   Console.WriteLine("you chose " + color)
}
```

Now imagine in production with a linear code and a bug happened in the process, you will test from start to finish just to debug. Now these "ideas/practice/patterns" comes in handy. Because it will be easier to find due to the separation of codes/methods/functions and address the issue you are currently facing.

Comment: building on your answer. I would like to clarify that if you would want to change the output text or there is something wrong in the method there is one place to change it and not N number of changes in N number of if statements.

Comment: @StianStandahl thanks for additional info on my answer